# How to get a proof of business address for mail forwarding service?

Tags: united-states, business, corporate-law

We would like to use mailing forwarding service as our business address in US. Banks require us to prove business address. How to get a proof of business address if we are using a mail forwarding service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each bank will decide for itself what it needs by way of evidence to satisfy its legal obligations. Ask them.